# Example (6) Section 1.1. Walters' Ergodic Theory

Tags: measure-theory, proof-explanation, ergodic-theory

The following is from Walters' Ergodic Theory book :

[image]

Blue : 1- How $m$ is defined based on $\mu$? 2- If spaces are all sets of integers where does measurable *rectangles* come from?! 3- How $m(T^{-1}A) = m(A)$ holds?

Red : 4- How T is measure preserving? 5- How $T^{-1}$ is measure preserving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First $X$ is just the set of (bi infinity) sequences of element of $Y$ and $T$ is just the shift in the sequence, you change the indices by $n \mapsto n+1$.

Now the measure $m$ is as follow $m(.....i....)=p_i$ that is the measure of the set of sequences having $I$ at a given position is $p_i$. And then $$
m(...i_1 i_2 - i_l....)=p_1p_2-p_l
$$
Where "$...$" mean any number and "$-$" mean given number.

This answer 1 and 2.

3, 4 and 5 are now just verifications.

I hope it is clear, comment if you need more details.

Comment: Still couldn't understand $m$ : What is $m(\dots 1, 1, 1, \dots)$ for example? Is it $p_1^{\infty}$ or $p_1 \times {\infty}$ which both are $\infty$! And I think $m=\infty$ so what's the use? Why didn't you consider other positions of numbers in the sequence when calculating $m$ and how the rule is? ... [I think you are right about Qs3,4,5 if I get a clear meaning of $m$ I can probably answer them as well or if you please guide them I can understand $m$ better?]

Comment: Let's called $[i]_j$ the set of all sequence that have $i$ at the position $j$. Then we set $m([i]_j)=p_i$. That's what I meant. Notice that it do not depend of $j$.

Comment: Then you want that there is no correlation between two position that is $m([k]_l \cap [i]_j)=p_k p_l$ if $l$ and $j$ are different. That is the measure of the set of sequences having $k$ at the $l$ position and $i$ at the $j$ position is $p_i p_k$

Comment: You can take a look at Wikipedia but I am not convict it is easier https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_scheme